# Returning a vector, is RVO or a move constructor being applied here?

Tags: c++, vector, move, move-semantics, rvo

I have a class, which has a std::vector data member. I then have a simple get member function which simply returns the data member by value.

```
class X{
    public:
    vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> z;

    vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> X::getVector(){
        return z;
    }
};
```

When I call the following C++:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>> my_vec = obj->getVector();
```

this x86 is produced:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>> my_vec = obj->getVector();
mov         rdx,qword ptr [r8+20h]  
test        rdx,rdx  
je          boost::boost::+3DCh (013F0F690Ch)  
lea         rcx,[x]  
call        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> > >::vector (013F0E9700h)
```

I am expecting either return-value optimization (RVO) to be applied, or the `std::vector` move constructor. However, I am unable to deduce which from the x86?

Comment: You use the return value in the declaration so copy construction applied. I am assuming you are not using C++11 so no move construction

Answer (score 1):

No, a member is never automatically moved. That would unexpectedly invalidate `this`.

The member `z` is copied to a temporary, which is then either moved or RVO is applied. Since you only see one constructor call, it looks like RVO.

Comment: Does the x86 show any of this? I'd be interested to learn how to recognize this in future.

Comment: Well, I mentioned that there is only one constructor call (or function call at all), and since a copy must be reflected in a constructor call, there seems to be RVO. However, we don't usually read executable code like this; it's easier and more reliable to single-step through it with the debugger. In particular, it looks like the function has been inlined and there's a null check around it.

Answer (score 0):

RVO is really a very basic and old optimization for compiler even since cfront. The compiler will try to construct the object in place if possible, and get rid of any copy/move.
In your case, it is same as:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>> my_vec(obj->z);
```

If you want to make sure no extra copy/move is invoked, just reutrn a reference from getVector();

Comment: Sorry I think you misread my Q. From the x86 I have provided, what is happening exactly? So you mention RVO, can you see RVO in the x86?